# How PostGIS stores COG ranges?

Tags: postgis

PostGIS can use out-db rasters, stored as Cloud Optimised GeoTIFF (COG) in external storage, like S3 or GCS. PostGIS will use HTTP Range Requests to fetch parts of the TIFF.

How does PostGIS know which byte range to request? I don't see such information here:

```
select b.rid, (b.meta).*, (b.bandmeta).* from (select rid, st_metadata(rast) as meta, st_bandmetadata(rast, 1) as bandmeta from my_tiled_remote_raster) as b;

| rid | upperleftx | upperlefty | width | height | scalex | scaley | skewx | skewy | srid | numbands | pixeltype | nodatavalue | isoutdb | path | outdbbandnum | filesize | filetimestamp |
| 1 | -14930329.0619462 | 6912576.8945718445 | 256 | 256 | 3738.064687613865 | -3738.064687613865 | 0 | 0 | 3857 | 1 | 64BF | NULL | true | /vsigs/my-bucket/my-file.grib2.tiff | 1 | 23594839 | 1659367574 |
(...other tiles for the same TIFF...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostGIS knows only the location of the out-db raster. GDAL drivers https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_gdal_enabled_drivers.html are doing the hard work. When the type of the out-db raster is COG the driver that gets used is https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html and it knows how to read the required metadata from the TIFF headers and Image Filed Directories and finally create the HTTP Range Requests for accessing the raster data.